# Can I track repo clone activity in GitHub Enterprise?

Tags: git, git-clone, github-enterprise

I know GitHub provides a way to view the number of clones (e.g. "traffic") but I was looking for a way, in GitHub Enterprise, to track the "who" and "where", regarding our repos being cloned internally. I'm sure hooks could be written to store said info in a DB, for example, but was hoping someone already had some slick way to do this. It doesn't appear this data is available in the "Audit Log", unless I am not searching properly? I'm surprised Enterprise doesn't provide a 'canned' method to track this ... seems reasonable, from a security perspective anyhow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible to track "traffic" on GitEnterprise.

Edit (12/2/18):

Evidence in the below links! Case Closed.

Check https://help.github.com/articles/about-repository-graphs/. This is the root page for Repository Graphs.
On the right, you can click on different versions of GitHub to access corresponding documentation.

When you click on GitHub.com, you see below text.

> A repository's graphs give you information on ***traffic***, projects that depend on the reposi...

Where as Enterprise versions show

> A repository's graphs give you information on contributors and commits to the repository, and a reposi....

Does not talk about **traffic** in this case.

And this is the documentation page for **traffic**

https://help.github.com/articles/viewing-traffic-to-a-repository/